# Can UI elements be included inside a .a library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My client wants to make a library in which all the processing and UIelements will be inside the library and He will extend his already existing app by using this library.. can you quote some example where this has already been done?

Comment: As far as i know third party dylib are not allowed in iphone

Comment: And archive libraries are allowed? An a file is roughly just a zip of few dylib files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot include resource files (like images or XIB-Files) in a static library (*.a).
That means you have to create the UI elements in code.
Creation of UIKit-Elements is simple:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,20)];
[someView addSubview:label];
```

If you want to create custom views (UIView subclass) you'll have to do the drawing with Core Graphics.
As an alternative you could load resources from the web.

As an example, the [Testflight SDK](https://testflightapp.com/sdk/) is released as a static library that uses some custom UI for its in-app features. I guess the resources are loaded from the web and cached in the app.